# multiple ssh commands for port forwarding in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have to stablish two VPN connections to different servers, and afterwards execute six port forwarding commands. Currently I open a console for each of these operations by hand, so that they run in parallel. I would like to make all these actions an Ansible playbook.

My ansible attempted file uses async: 25200 (seconds) to account for 7 hours of connection

```
---
- name: start of the day tasks on localhost
  hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - name: start Kerio and connect to server1 VPN
      shell: /etc/init.d/kerio-kvc start; ssh user@server1_ip
    - name: connect to server_2 VPN
      shell: ssh user@server2_ip
      async: 25200
      poll: 0
    - name: instantiate RabbitMQ in server_1
      shell: ssh -L 5680:localhost:5672 user@server1_ip
      async: 25200
      poll: 0
    - name: instantiate RabbitMQ in server_2
      shell: ssh -L 5690:localhost:5672 user@server2_ip
      async: 25200
      poll: 0
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What exactly is your question? Does this example work for you?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The example doesn't work. The question is how can I write an Ansible playbook that stablishes two VPN connections in parallel, and afterwards executes port forwarding commands on each VPN, such as ssh -L 5680:localhost:5672 user@server1_ip

Comment: I am questioning the use of `async` here. Have you considered the alternative of using [`autossh`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/autossh) to facilitate the port-forwarding, and shut it down again at a later time, in a separate playbook execution? Or better yet, installing a `cron` job together with `autossh`, that would shut it down automatically?